# How to trim a word from a line

Tags: powershell

Does anyone know how to trim this, so that I will get output as (Red Hat VirtIO). I tried like below and I ma only getting output as Red nothing else. Please help

```
$KVMName = $KVM.split(" ")[0].split("=")[1].Trim()
```

Here `$KVM` value is  `@{devicename=Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter; driverversion=100.74.104.13200}`

After trim I want the output as **Red Hat VirtIO**

Comment: Your inital question was about how to remove the last word. Now you wan't to trim two words. You also didn't clarify whether you just want to remove also the word Ethernet Adapter or always the last two words. Since your inital question was about removing the last word, my answer correlates to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple *regex*:

```
"Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter" -replace '\s+\w+\s+\w+$'
```

In your case it should be:

```
$KVMName = $KVM.devicename -replace '\s+\w+\s+\w+$'
```

**Explanation:**

- `\w+` matches any word character
- `$` asserts position at the end of the string
- `\s+` matches any whitespace character

Comment: It would work if `$KVM` is defined as `$KVM = @{devicename="Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter"; driverversion="100.74.104.13200"}` (I'm _not_ a downvoter).

Comment: @JosefZ True. But that is probably the case since you can't create an object that way - right?

Comment: We _don't know_ anything about `$KVM` type from the OP's vaguely formulated original question (not given a [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

```
$KVM=@{devicename="Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter"; driverversion="100.74.104.13200"} 

($KVM.devicename -split ' ', 4)[0..2] -join ' '
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.